# Linker error with undefined reference to templated constructor

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create templated function, which takes as input a vector of type T and divides it among several threads. This is done by constructing objects of templated type T "VectorWorker"  with iterators to the beginning and end of the data they need to process.

I am running into a linker error, where the templated std::vec::const_iterators I am attempting to pass to the VectorWorker constructor is not finding a corresponding constructor. My understanding is that the types of the parameters I am calling the constructor with, differs from the types of the parameters in the constructor I have defined.

The relevant lines of the templated function which constructs the VectorWorkers are:

```
/* function to create initial worker that spawns more workers*/
template <typename T>
void makeWorkers(const std::vector<T>& initializerVector)
{
  int quotient = initializerVector.size()/NUMTHREADS; // divide by number of threads
  int remainder = initializerVector.size()%NUMTHREADS; //find remainder after division which will have to be distributed

  //store the iterators for all our workers in a 2 X NUMTHREADS matrix. Where first column is each workers beginning iterator
  //and second column is each worker's ending iterator
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator itArray[NUMTHREADS][2];

  VectorWorker<T> workerArray [NUMTHREADS]; //instantiate array to hold all workers
  std::thread threadArray[NUMTHREADS]; //instantiate array to hold threads which will run worker's work() method

  //The first "remainder" distances should be quotient+1, the remaining should just be quotient to yield
  // remainder(quotient+1)+(N-remainder)(quotient) = N*Quotient+remainder


  itArray[0][0] = initializerVector.begin();
  if(remainder ==0)
  {
    remainder=NUMTHREADS; //to prevent division by zero
    itArray[0][1] = initializerVector.cbegin()+quotient-1; //limit distance between first two iterators to quotient
  }
  else
    itArray[0][1] = initializerVector.cbegin()+quotient-1; //The distance between first two iterators should be quotient+1


  for (int i=1; i<NUMTHREADS; ++i)
  {
    itArray[i][0]=itArray[i-1][0]+quotient+1-(int)(i<remainder);
    itArray[i][1]=itArray[i-1][1]+quotient+1-(int)(i<remainder);
  }

  /*
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin;
  begin = itArray[0][0];
*/

  // construct all worker objects
  for( int i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; ++i)
  {
    workerArray[i]=VectorWorker<T>(itArray[i][0],itArray[i][1]); //copy assignment into default initialized array objects
  }
```

and the templated class definition for VectorWorker is:

```
template <typename T>
class VectorWorker
{
public:
    VectorWorker<T>() = default;
    VectorWorker<T>( typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin,  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end);
    void Work() const
    {
      std::cout<<"I worked"<<std::endl;

      return;
    };

private:
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator beginIt; /* Stores value of left iterator that defines data for this worker */
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator endIt; /* Stores value of right iterator that defines data for this worker */
};
```

Finally, the linker error I am receiving is:

```
CMakeFiles/P2.dir/fft2d.cc.o: In function `void makeWorkers<Complex*>(std::vector<Complex*, std::allocator<Complex*> > const&)':
undefined reference to `VectorWorker<Complex*>::VectorWorker(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Complex* const*, std::vector<Complex*, std::allocator<Complex*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Complex* const*, std::vector<Complex*, std::allocator<Complex*> > >)'
```

EDIT: MWE that produces the error on: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#define NUMTHREADS 4

template <typename T>
class VectorWorker
{
public:
    VectorWorker<T>() = default;
    VectorWorker<T>( typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin,  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end);
    void Work() const
    {
      std::cout<<"I worked"<<std::endl;

      return;
    };

private:
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator beginIt; /* Stores value of left iterator that defines data for this worker */
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator endIt; /* Stores value of right iterator that defines data for this worker */
};

using namespace std;
/* function to create initial worker that spawns more workers*/
template <typename T>
void makeWorkers(const std::vector<T>& initializerVector)
{
  int quotient = initializerVector.size()/NUMTHREADS; // divide by number of threads
  int remainder = initializerVector.size()%NUMTHREADS; //find remainder after division which will have to be distributed

  //store the iterators for all our workers in a 2 X NUMTHREADS matrix. Where first column is each workers beginning iterator
  //and second column is each worker's ending iterator
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator itArray[NUMTHREADS][2];

  VectorWorker<T> workerArray [NUMTHREADS]; //instantiate array to hold all workers
  std::thread threadArray[NUMTHREADS]; //instantiate array to hold threads which will run worker's work() method

  //The first "remainder" distances should be quotient+1, the remaining should just be quotient to yield
  // remainder(quotient+1)+(N-remainder)(quotient) = N*Quotient+remainder


  itArray[0][0] = initializerVector.begin();
  if(remainder ==0)
  {
    remainder=NUMTHREADS; //to prevent division by zero
    itArray[0][1] = initializerVector.cbegin()+quotient-1; //limit distance between first two iterators to quotient
  }
  else
    itArray[0][1] = initializerVector.cbegin()+quotient-1; //The distance between first two iterators should be quotient+1


  for (int i=1; i<NUMTHREADS; ++i)
  {
    itArray[i][0]=itArray[i-1][0]+quotient+1-(int)(i<remainder);
    itArray[i][1]=itArray[i-1][1]+quotient+1-(int)(i<remainder);
  }

  /*
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin;
  begin = itArray[0][0];
*/

  // construct all worker objects
  for( int i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; ++i)
  {
    workerArray[i]=VectorWorker<T>(itArray[i][0],itArray[i][1]); //copy assignment into default initialized array objects
  }
  return;
}



int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    std::vector<int*> testVec = {new int*, new int*};
    makeWorkers(testVec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: The code compiles fine using gcc (g++). Do you have the full MWE?

Comment: @Arash, appreciate you taking a look. I have added a MWE at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the second constructor of `VectorWorker` but you never implemented it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class VectorWorker
{
public:
    VectorWorker<T>( typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin,  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end)
    {
       I NEED IMPLEMENTATION <-------------------------
    }

};

template <typename T>
void makeWorkers(const std::vector<T>& initializerVector)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator a,b;
    VectorWorker<T>(a,b);
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int*> testVec = {new int*, new int*};
  makeWorkers(testVec);
  return 0;
}
```